# C++ - Thread Pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, lambda, threadpool

for a university exercise I had to build a thread pool using classes. I started working on it but I encounterd some problems.
My idea was to use ASYNC to generate the threads but compiler told me that the function that I had to provide to async should have been a static function. The problem was that if the main function of the thread was static also every variable had to be static and the threads can't reference all the variables mutex included.
After some tries I came out with this solution but I don't know if it's good to proceed like that

```
class JobScheduler01 {
private:
    unsigned int numOfThread;
    std::vector<std::future<int>> pool;
    //std::vector<std::thread> pool_thread;

    std::list<Job> runningQueue;
    std::list<Job> waitingQueue;

    int ThreadMain(); // <- infinite loop

    std::mutex m;
public:

    JobScheduler01();
    ~JobScheduler01();
    void Start(); // <- start all the threads
};
```

```
void JobScheduler01::Start() {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numOfThread; i++){
        pool.push_back(std::async([this](){return ThreadMain();})); // <------ QUESTION
    }
}

int JobScheduler01::ThreadMain() {
    // main loop here
    m.lock();
    std::cout << "thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";
    m.unlock();
    return 0;
}
```

I created a lambda fuction that just start the main loop, but I'm not sure if it's right.
Does this apporoach generate some sort of monsters? or is it ok?
Which could be a better solution? 
Is it better to use async or to ue std::thread and join them in the destructor?

Comment: Your assignment is to create a thread pool, but `std::async` _uses_ a thread pool. I doubt that the instructor will give you credit for a solution that simply uses somebody else's thread pool. You should ask your instructor to explain what they want in more detail, but my _guess_ is that you are expected to create `std::thread` instances that loop forever (or, until told to stop) picking _task_ objects from a blocking queue, and _performing_ them. A "task" would be an object with some virtual member function, and the worker threads "perform" the task by calling the virtual function.

Comment: first of all I want to thank you for your reply. I didn't know that async uses a thread pool.
I followed your suggestion and tried with std::thread but I encountered the same problem I had with async. I also asked to my instructur who told me, as suggestion, to try to use std::packaged_task. 

I posted another question on the same topic if u would like to check it I would really appreciate it.

In any case, thank you very much for the help. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to understand a thread pool implementation in pure c, like ones [here](https://nachtimwald.com/2019/04/12/thread-pool-in-c/) and [here](https://github.com/Pithikos/C-Thread-Pool) and then starting to use c++ to replace (or in your case implement) parts of the c code (this can be library code like std::thread, std::vector, std::mutex, smart pointers or c++ language features like references, templates and lambdas).